# Does Realm offer a callback when Results<Object> done loading? - Realm, Swift, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, callback, realm, loading

I have an a view that displays a list of checklists that are fetched from Realm, and displayed via an @Published property in an observable object.

**Because the checklists can take 1-2 seconds to appear in the list, I want to show a loading state and replace it with the list of checklists when those checklists are fully loaded**.

Does Realm swift offer a callback I could use?

```
final class Store: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var checklists: Results<Checklist>
    var realm: Realm
    
    init(realm: Realm) {
        self.realm = realm
        checklists = realm.objects(Checklist.self).sorted(
            byKeyPath: "lastModifiedDate",
            ascending: false
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `NotificationToken`

Comment: They do! As @ElTomato said, one option is through a Notification token. See [React to changes](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/react-to-changes/) in the documentation taking note of `case .initial:` which fires when the data has been completely loaded. I am concerned that data is taking 1-2 seconds to load; that must be a substantial amount of data.